# How to remove information in Magento catalog, but only for specific product type

Tags: magento

I am wondering how can I delete this two divs - 
 in Magento catalog, but only for specific product type. In short, I would like to have product type which would appear in catalog only with product-image and product-name, without - price, Out of stock, Add to Wishlist, Add to Compare.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to load different layout updates depending on loaded product type. You can see an example of how it's done in Magento for configurable products here: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L275-L287
It's possible because view action of product controller makes this to be executed: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php#L59-L60

Comment: Hi! thanks! but I don't get how it's working, I've created Virtual product, then I've deleted everything from PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual in XML, refreshed cache, but it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ArturKlassen I think you don't understand Magento layout system completely. Just to test: remove everything inside `PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual` xml tag and insert this line:
`<remove name="header"/>`
If you open the page of this virtual product, you'll see that there's no header. Otherwise, you probably edit a wrong file (different theme).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the design for any product from the admin.
You need to create a separate theme with a different product page which will have only the attributes you would like.
Then you can select the design for that specific product. Please see the screenshot, how you can change design for any product
[image]